# What should be done with popular answers that are copy/pasted from copyrighted works?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

While perusing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/1287251) I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177063/1287251), which is incredibly popular. Clicking its link to the comp.lang.c FAQ's page, it's obvious the answer is a complete copy'n'paste of that whole FAQ entry.

[The book is copyrighted](http://c-faq.com/expr/copyright.html) and requires "explicit permission" to retransmit the online content. I'm no lawyer, but this answer seems like it's overstepping some copyright boundaries.

What should be done with highly popular answers that are just copy/pastes of copyrighted works? I don't think the popularity of the answer should be taken into account, as that's irrelevant to copyright, and I've thought of the following courses of action:

1. Do nothing. Let the copyright owner file a DMCA takedown request or flag the answer if they don't like it. It sounds reasonable, but I hate to just "look the other way" when something looks fishy because it's "not my problem" (and I actually think things like this are partially "my problem" because it affects the community I'm a part of).
2. Flag it for moderator review. This is what I'm leaning towards, but I know moderators get lots of flags so I always feel guilty adding to their workload. While I'll probably do this, I'd also like to probe the community to make sure I'm responding to the situation correctly by doing this.
3. Comment on the answer suggesting the answerer changes the answer to have more original content or commentary. This might work, but the answer has received 217 upvotes for what it currently says. Drastically modifying it into something else seems like a bait-n-switch.

Comment: No reason to flag *that* post for moderator attention considering you've brought it up on Meta. Every moderator is sure to see it. But I understand you're also asking this question more generally, so you'll know what to do in the future. (This happens distressingly often.)

Comment: @CodyGray: Okay, I went ahead and flagged that particular answer. But yeah, general guidance on a future course of action is what I'm seeking.

Comment: From the copyright of the copied source "The on-line content may be accessed freely for personal use but may not be published or retransmitted without explicit permission. " This sounds quite unambigous to me.

Comment: I read a bit more about DMCA (still not a lawyer) and it seems that "§ 512(c) also requires that the OSP [..] not be aware of the presence of infringing material or know any facts or circumstances that would make infringing material apparent" [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Copyright_Infringement_Liability_Limitation_Act#Safe_harbor_provision_for_online_storage_-_.C2.A7_512.28c.29) which might mean that at least since this question here has been opened two days ago, SO would be aware of it and would have to remove the infringing content already now. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Trilarion: There are several requirements that go into a valid DMCA takedown notice.  Mere awareness of a potential copyright problem doesn't satisfy any of those requirements.  I'm not a lawyer, but I would guess that the "awareness" issue has to do with OSP's that willfully and deliberately host infringing material on a regular basis as part of their service, and are clearly aware that they are doing so.  The bar for making that determination appears to be quite high, judging from recent lawsuits against Grooveshark and their ilk.

Comment: anything and everything

Comment: It should at the very least have been posted Community Wiki. It's offensive that someone has just stolen a wall of text from an external resource, dumped it in an answer then claimed gazillion points of rep from it. Not a high quality answer in the slightest, and zero effort on the part of its supposed author.

Comment: [status-resolved] → http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316911/what-should-be-done-with-popular-answers-that-are-copy-pasted-from-copyrighted-w/316989#comment310140_316989

Answer (score 30):

Follow the steps outlined in [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) to report it to moderators.

Yes, moderators aren't copyright lawyers. But that doesn't mean they're stupid, or that they can't, or shouldn't, act in blatant cases of copyright infringement.

In cases where a massive amount of, or the *entire answer* is obviously copy-pasted from a protected resource (i.e. it would fulfill the criteria for plagiarism even if there were no copyright infringement), moderators are likely to step in.

In those cases, we don't lean back and wait for the author to kick off the DMCA process, nor should we.

The use of short paragraphs or quotes from a copyrighted resource, on the other hand, is likely to be [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use). In borderline cases of fair use, it's unlikely that mods will do anything.

Comment: My only issue with this answer is that it seems to equate plagiarism to copyright infringement. In OP's example the original source was cited, so while it may be copyright infringement, it's not plagiarism.

Comment: See Pops' answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141775), which references [this article](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2012/04/april-newsletter-2). In general, we *don't* handle copyright claims ourselves, but answers that 1) copy content wholesale with little apparent regard for the original question, or 2) actually steal content, i.e. do not comply with the guidelines in http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing and thus constitute plagiarism, are subject to moderator action - and this is irrespective of the copyright policies of the origin of the text.

Comment: To reiterate, if the issue is less of copyvio and more of a very low quality answer or an answer that violates site rules *anyway*, we will gladly handle it.

Comment: @BoltClock Do you think a full copy without changes from a Link on the help page merits a VLQ deletion?

Comment: The mention of fair use is a critical one. Basically, anything without attribution is plagiarism (which is already covered by moderators) and most everything else falls under fair use. The small fraction of posts that don't fall under those two categories should probably be dealt with by the copyright holder (keep in mind that they might _**want**_ the post to stay up because it may drives sales/adoption of their media by giving people a taste of relevant information).

Answer (score 27):

Our terms of service state that users can only provide contributions that they have the right to contribute. Then we also must consider that copyright law in the United States can be even more confusing than our tax code, and we don't expect everyone to know the ins-and-outs of it. To this, please always try to assume good faith on behalf of the contributor, especially when they make it clear that the work is not their own.

Moderators do not intervene in cases of *copyright*, they intervene only in cases of very apparent *plagiarism*. And the remedy for this is to request that the person provide appropriate credit through proper citation, or delete the post. In other words, moderators should be involved where the contribution was very clearly *not* in good faith.

The DMCA provides a framework for copyright holders to request that content be taken down *if they care to do so*. This involves a short, but clear trail of paperwork and we comply with any properly submitted request. It is up to the copyright holder, however, to initiate this process. We can't be sure who they are, we don't know if they'd object - and Stack Overflow gets *thousands* of posts every day.

US law provides a safe harbor framework for this very reason - we can't *possibly* deal with possible infringement on a 100% proactive basis, which is why the law says that our responsibility lies in complying with proper requests to remove things. Doing anything else is giving up ground that US law affords us.

But that's not to say that we're *not* proactive when we should be, or bad netizens.

As others have noted, it's more a question of *our* standards - and we very strongly encourage people to make sure the majority of their answers are their own creation. It's fine to cite, it's fine to build upon examples, but *you* need to own the narrative. Mods are very picky about this, and enforce it regularly. Copying without proper citation, or a pattern of wholesale copying even with citation is going to get you a moderator message at the least.

We also deal with waves of spam where people copy great content from other sites in an effort to build up enough rep to be able to edit or bypass some of the new user restrictions. We delete this without question or hesitation because it's obviously *in bad faith*.

There was a time when we were trying to find the right balance - especially in the broader network. We didn't want people creating sites where they just cited Wikipedia articles - even though it's perfectly okay to copy Wikipedia with attribution. It wasn't really clear how much was 'too much'.  So you will find some verbatim copies of manual pages, excerpts of language FAQs, passages from standards and the like - without much narrative at all from the person posting it.

These don't measure up to the standards we hold today, but they *were* good-faith, valuable contributions at the time. Removing them on the presumption that the actual copyright holder *might* consider the use as an infringement seems like a bad way to go - especially given that requesting removal is (more or less) a very painless and convenient process.

The law is structured in a manner that we don't have to think about possible copyright infringement due to something someone posts too much. We should, definitely be very proactive against *bad actors* - but let's also enjoy the value of not having to worry about it otherwise (unless we get a request, which is easily and routinely handled), as the law provides.

---

Side note: We do [report requests](https://lumendatabase.org/notices/search?term=stack+overflow&sort_by=) to chillingeffects.org - and yes some of them are notices to remove code from assignments *here on meta*.

Comment: This is why [SOPA scared the hell out of us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sopa) - well, one of the reasons.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that in a case like this with a very easy to understand copyright notice like "The on-line content may be accessed freely for personal use but may not be published or retransmitted without explicit permission. " the law (in the US) does not require you to take it down but you can actually wait until the copyright owner actually demands it? Well, if so, I withdraw any objection.

Comment: "These don't measure up to the standards we hold today, but they were [..] valuable contributions at the time." I actually wonder if these contributions also have still value today or if they could be replaced easily by a summary of the content? After all just copying seems like it can never be specific to the question unless the copied text exactly answered it. Also if there is already a template, reproducing the wisdom in one's own words shouldn't be too difficult. One could guess that the value of these contributions now is rather low. Of course, if you want to keep them, do it.

Answer (score 23):

Here is some general guidance. You suggest this:

> Do nothing. Let the copyright owner file a DMCA takedown request or flag the answer if they don't like it. It sounds reasonable, but I hate to just "look the other way" when something looks fishy because it's "not my problem" (and I actually think things like this are partially "my problem" because it affects the community I'm a part of).

**Yes, you should really let a copyright owner file a DMCA takedown.**

Why?

The fact of the matter is that it is in fact difficult for third parties to know for sure who owns the copyright of a piece of text (be it code or prose). For instance, the fact that the piece of text appears in a copyrighted work does not entail that the person who has copyright of the work has copyright over the specific piece of text in question. If I publish a book that contains a song that has fallen into the public domain, I don't gain a copyright over the song, even if someone copies the song from my book and provides a link to my book.

Let the person who thinks they own copyright over the problematic text or code file a DMCA takedown. **If you feel a moral obligation to act with regards to a specific case, you could contact the person whom you think has copyright and tell them about what you found.**

In his [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316951/1906307), Pekka brings up the **issue of plagiarism**. Copying someone else's work without attribution is plagiarism. However, whether a copyright violation occurred does not determine whether plagiarism occurred, for a use can be: neither plagiarism nor a copyright violation, both plagiarism and a copyright violation, a copyright violation but not plagiarism (e.g. selling PDFs of a book whose copyright is not yours; a faithful copy will show who is the author), plagiarism but not a copyright violation (e.g. taking a couple sentence out of a book without attribution). It does not matter whether the copied work is in the public domain, or whether the copy would be fair use under copyright. **If you find plagiarism, flag it, but note that this won't lead to any action on the basis of copyright.**

If you do put up a flag that claims plagiarism *and* a copyright violation, the copyright part of your flag will be ignored.

Comment: Well, at the very least, the reposter should have made it community-wiki.

Comment: Disagree. When it's obvious and blatant that an answer was lifted from a copyrighted resource, we should not lean back and wait for the remote possibility of the author discovering it and filing a DMCA request. Copying protected content is a matter of five seconds and three mouse clicks; filing a DMCA request one of much more time and effort.

Comment: I also disagree.  And I think if it looks like it's official policy that "if you see copyrighted material don't tell us" then that weakens stackoverflow's case if there's ever a legal issue on this.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Maybe a message to the copyright owner would be sufficient. the owner could then let us know if he wants it taken down. For all we know the owner is happy with the attention. It may even be the owner posting.

Comment: This answer seems to be saying that's its a bit tricky to be sure so we shouldn't even try to question it. Worrying how many upvotes this answer has considering the amount of answers on stack overflow that are reused/redistributed every day based on the cc-by-sa license.

Comment: @rdans I guessed you missed the bit that says "If you feel a moral obligation to act with regards to a specific case, you could contact the person whom you think has copyright and tell them about what you found."

Comment: I saw it but I don't believe it's sufficient because it doesn't protect other site users from unknowingly breaching copyright laws by redistributing under the CC-BY-SA license.

Comment: @rdans contacting the author is the most moral and efficient solution. it's the most moral solution because you're also informing the author that a potential violation occurred vs just fixing it and "sweeping it under the rug", which means the author may never find out about the violation. it's the most efficient solution because determining copyright infringement is very difficult and the author has the best ability to determine whether a post infringes on their copyright (contrast this with determining plagiarism, which is relatively simple to identify by any person).

Comment: It's not plagiarism if proper attribution is made.  In the referenced post, the material is clearly attributed to the C-Faq website with a link to the original.  I remember when SO was first getting started the question arose whether to just link to external content or to both link and copy paste since the original site might "go away" or become inaccessible, and it's my recollection that the consensus at the time was both link and copy.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes: Indeed, it was attributed right at the top; not plagiarism. I don't think Louis meant your answer was plagiarism, just addressing plagiarism in the abstract. That said, it's important to use blockquote markup for quoted material, to clearly differentiate it from original content.

Comment: @FuzzyTree I don't disagree that the author should be contacted. My argument is that this doesn't go far enough. It assumes that the author is the only one affected by this, when in fact it affects all users who choose to use the materials. These users are making use of the answer in good faith on the assumption that they are permitted to do so, including redistribution under the CC-BY-SA license.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "I don't think Louis meant your answer was plagiarism, just addressing plagiarism in the abstract." This is 100% correct.

Comment: @rdans: The CC-BY-SA license cannot subvert an author's original copyrights, and it is clear in the answer that the poster does not own the material.  So anyone who thinks they now have the freedom to use the material as they choose (just because it has been posted to Stack Overflow) has a flawed thinking process.

Comment: You have to let the IP holder make the claim. There is a very important reason why (via YouTube shenanagins). There is a practice of IP highjacking. In short, a 4th party delivers content claiming to be IP holder when they stole/similar the data. Then they reap the benefit of IP claims. This happens on YT as people post audio sample packs on zero-day and then make claims against fair use works. I have defended this a few times personally -- and won 100%. If the content is detrimental to the network/resource that is another issue. The supposed IP holder may not be legal, not SO's problem ever.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The whole practice of making a content archive available is fundamentally and inextricably linked to that "flawed thinking process".

Comment: @BenVoigt: My point is that you can't rely simply on the mere presence of material on Stack Overflow as a guarantee that the material has a valid CC-BY-SA license, nor does SE make that claim.  The only claim they make is that they have Terms of Service that require you to license your contributions as CC-BY-SA, but contributors must still have the ability to do so.

Answer (score 22):

I am the author of the copy-and-pasted content that sparked this question.

I have been aware of the "plagiarism" and have been mildly -- but only mildly -- annoyed by it.  It's a good answer to its question (if I do say so myself).  But it certainly deserves, I would certainly appreciate, a little more credit.  (I considered asking Robert S. Barnes -- with a smiley -- if I could share in his 215 rep points.)

<s>I would not insist that the content be taken down.</s> It would be much better to post an excerpt, with an external read-this-longer-answer-for-more link.

To the general question, I agree that wholesale copy-and-paste of significant quantities of copyrighted material onto SO should require attribution and permission.  My opinion would be that unattributed material, once discovered, should be preemptively taken down, should not wait for any official takedown notices.

It can also be asked whether it would be preferable to merely link to (instead of copy) such material.  But it can then be asked whether SO intends to be a standalone repository that does not rely on external links.  I am not nearly enough of an SO insider to pass any opinion on those questions.

Comment: You are mixing copyright and plagiarism. You say "I agree that wholesale copy-and-paste of significant quantities of copyrighted material onto SO should require require attribution and permission." See, *whether the material is copyrighted or not*, if it has been copied and pasted "wholesale", then it is plagiarism and not allowed on SO. This does not depend on copyright status at all. Regarding links, we don't like link-only answers so a link would definitely have to be accompanied by a summary or a quote.

Comment: With regard to "We don't like link-only answers", I'm not sure that's the best policy.  Suppose there's a question with a nearly perfect answer elsewhere, that no one on SO can improve upon.  What's wrong with a link-only answer in that case?  Links are what the World-Wide-Web is based on.  For SO to say "We want to be standalone, we don't like anyone else's answers, we want all our own answers" is to potentially insult the authors of those other answers and to make them less generous about not objecting to copyright violation.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Well, SO answers are for answers, SO is explicitly not a link-aggregator. What should be done in such cases is simple: Paraphrase the high points, and link to the thorough and in-depth resource presenting it perfectly. The execution might be a bit more involved ;-) Regarding enforcing third-party agreements and copyright: There's a reason SE funnels that to DMCA requests: Over-enforcement and greatly increased liability, mostly, if they decided to police it themselves.

Comment: Unattributed material is generally removed on the grounds of plagiarism, that's always been the case. What we struggled with was how _much_ ownership should someone have in a post? The answer to that is most of it, most of the time. If we see a patterns of copying and pasting (even with proper credit) - moderators do generally delete the posts while reaching out to the person to let them know where they went wrong. It took a little while to be able to articulate what _is_ too much when it comes to attributed copy - so there are some old posts that went overboard by today's standard.

Comment: Just as a clarification and for this case: Do you give permission or not or only under certain circumstances (like an shortened version with a link and an attribution note)? If not or only under certain conditions, I would say that SO is then well adviced to modify or take down that post. You probably cannot have a more clear copyright case than this.

Comment: @Trilarion: I'm going to wait another 24 hours and make a decision.

Comment: Steve, how would you feel if the answer was a [Community Wiki answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)?  That way, no points are awarded, but it is still eligible for acceptance and upvotes.

Comment: I always thought that StackOverflow and associates (loosely) adhered to [Agreement on Guidelines for Classroom Copying  
in Not-For-Profit Educational Institutions  
with respect to books and periodicals](http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ21.pdf) (pag. 6), though I know more about spanish legislation than USA's. On one hand, it seems reasonable. On the other hand, legislation *rarely* has anything to do with reason.... unless a judge says so... Anyways, I think the *intention* and form are well-guided. It's clearly credited and for education.

Comment: I think the problem is, as someone else pointed out, is SO is distributing this content under another license.   So while you maybe okish with it existing here, you also need to be ok with the content being CC

Comment: @KeithNicholas Indeed, probably what Steve's mulling over by putting the decision off for ~24 hrs.

Comment: @KeithNicholas Indeed. Steve should be aware that if he agrees that part of his website can be published here under CC, then next time this very content can be copied from here (giving attribution, even be used commercially) without needing to ask him, but that's the only way to have any content here.

Comment: @SteveSummit I'm the offending copy and paster. I've greatly enjoyed your C FAQ material and read the whole thing many years ago.  When I saw that question 6 years ago your FAQ answer was the first thing that popped into my head as I felt it was the perfect answer and there was not anything that could really be added to it.  So I followed what I understood to be the stackoverflow policy of attribution with a link plus copy and paste.  If there is a mechanism available, I have no problem transferring the answer + rep to an account on your name, but I think the answer is perfect and should stay,

Comment: since I assume your purpose is to share your knowledge, and I'm sure the presence of this answer and link has driven significant traffic to your site.  That's actually something you should be able to check with your web host.  Please let me know what you would like me to do.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes: Thanks for your kind words (and the offer of a hypothetical rep transfer). My goal is indeed to teach people and share knowledge, but in the end, for a number of reasons which others on this page have explored well, that big an excerpt from the C FAQ list doesn't belong on Stackoverflow, so I've decided to ask that it be removed.  Nothing personal.

Comment: @SteveSummit OK, I will try and write up some kind of summary sometime over the next few days to replace it and with a link telling people to see the original for further information.  If you see I haven't, feel free to remind me.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes it's nice to see an issue amicably resolved in a professional manner by 2 member of StackOverflow. It makes a nice change from some of the hostility on this site - I applaud you both.

Comment: I never forgot this question completely and always wanted to write my own answer based on the C FAQ by Robert S. Barnes if Steve Summit wouldn't write anything, but I just read through all the answers of the question and they are fine. No additional answer is needed. Especially the superb answers by [Shafik Yaghmour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18260171/1536976) and [supercat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13729991/1536976) are more than enough to answer the question. So nothing to do really.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion its entirely wrong for stack overflow and the stack overflow community to ignore cases like this for this reason:

```
"user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required"
```

By allowing this content on the site this tells site users that they have a right to reuse/redistribute the answer when in fact they may not have that right.

At the very minimum we should be questioning cases like this in the comments so that other users know that the content may not be suitable for reuse or redistribution, with further action taken if the user does not respond or justify why they believe the content is allowed.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not a lawyer but it seems self-evident to me that StackOverflow should only host material that it has a right to do so. That means that users (probably in the terms of service) should promise to only publish material they have the right to publish - their own creative work, general knowledge, etc.

That has two major consequences for me:

1. Moderators must handle these cases if they need handling. If you have a suspicion that a post breaches a copyright, flag it and explain the suspicion. You may also comment on it. Moderators may seek legal guidance from StackOverflow lawyers if necessary but if the risk of a breach of copyright indeed is likely, the post has to be taken down. Obviously there is a bit of a gray zone.
2. Users should avoid such situations by finding alternative resources. Just linking to the copyrighted resources and summarizing in their own words the content of it may also be possible. There again is a gray zone when a summary becomes too extensive but in general a quite short summary is on the safe side. Problem with this is, that link-only answers are seen as low quality. So finding alternative resources is more important.

   You may want to ask for permission in case you want to quote from a copyrighted source when publishing content on StackOverflow. The copyright owner can of course always grant you the right to publish here.

In general, users should flag when they have a suspicion and moderators should take content down that is likely a breach of copyright. In the end, all the corner cases have to checked by StackOverflow legal department - after all they face the risk of getting sued. They may decide to not expose themselves too much or they may feel rather adventurous - it's up to them which risk tolerance they want to have.

Reading a bit more about the DMCA legislation in the US (still not a lawyer) it seems that "§ 512(c) also requires that the OSP [..] not be aware of the presence of infringing material or know any facts or circumstances that would make infringing material apparent" [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Copyright_Infringement_Liability_Limitation_Act#Safe_harbor_provision_for_online_storage_-_.C2.A7_512.28c.29) which might mean that at least since this question here has been opened, StackOverflow would be aware of it and would have to remove the infringing content immediately. In this particular case Steve Summit himself will probably decide soon what should be done with his content but in the general case this might mean that StackOverflow would have to act as soon as it gets knowledge (for example via a flag) of a possible copyright infringement (not only by the copyright holder himself).

Comment: I think it is mostly the responsibility of StackOverflow to have a policy on that. They are the ones who would get sued anyway.

Comment: If SE starts policing *some* copyright-violations, they assume responsibility for *all* of them. That's really not a smart move.

Comment: @Deduplicator They already have the responsibility for all of them, I think. What is your understanding of the law? That it only applies if you acknowledge it? I don't know if it's a smart move and I do not care too much about it. I just say what I think should be done if you abide by the law and usually that is the smartest option available. But it's up to StackOverflow what they think they should do about it. (Actually the "not doing anything" may be seen as kind of assistance in copyright infringements.)

Comment: This situation (requiring hosts to police all their users, always, in all things) is the very thing the DMCA was explicitly created to prevent, so no, this is a deeply flawed understanding of current law.

Comment: @NathanTuggy In this answer, I'm not requiring hosts to police all their users. I think you misunderstood me here. What I said was that you can (but not must) flag posts if you have a suspicion and that moderators should then act but only if a breach of copyright is likely. What you are saying is that in such clear cases as this the DMCA still does not require anything from you. That may be so (although SO does not only operate within the US) but then I still find it strange to voluntarily keep copyrighted material on this site even if you know it's a clear case of breach of copyright.

Comment: @Trilarion: Your saying "Moderators must" is what caused the misunderstanding, I think; that sounds like an obligation, which is precisely what we don't want to deal with.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ah, that's really a misunderstanding. I meant it as a categorization. Kind of: if it has to be dealt by someone, this someone must be a moderator. Doesn't mean he must do something at all time or even he must be patrolling the site constantly. Tried to make it more clear.

Answer (score -7):

In my personal opinion, and I am not a lawyer: If the post makes it explicitly clear where is is from (and the post in question does) and you are using as a just and righteous thing then it should be okay. You are agreeing with the author and you think that the author has put it as succinctly and clear as possible.

Finally if the author or copyright owner wants it taken down then he/she will in the first instance (hopefully) ask nicely to have it removed and then a mod should remove it.

Most authors I know have Google Alerts set up on their names, links to their work and various things so know when something of theirs is used and can see what context it is used in.

Comment: Can see why you're not a lawyer :)

Comment: But you are not posting off as your own work and surely fair use should apply.

Comment: "Fair use" is not carte blanche to just reproduce whatever you want. It is not blanket permission to completely ignore the licence of the original content. (Neither is the SO principle of "quote and link", even though the answer author seems to believe that somehow overrides the licence of the quoted text??). The way I understand it, "fair use" would probably allow for quoting of two or three sentences from the original text (which, conveniently, is what the SO answer author should have done).