# Is an answer (almost literally) copied from another site allowed?

Tags: discussion, answers

I am getting into MVC at the moment and I was searching the difference between `RenderBody()`, `RenderSection()` and `RenderPage()`. Then I noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32644883/3410196) is just copying [this article from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383145/RenderBody-RenderPage-and-RenderSection-methods-in) and there is no reference or anything to it.

As you can see, the answerer just copied 2 of the images and adds a title above them (also copied!). There is no original content added by the answerer himself.

My question is: **Is this acceptable?** Of course it's a good answer but he clearly just copied it. Is this allowed? Is it allowed if he would link the website?

Comment: Absolutely not. Flag for moderator attention with the original link.

Comment: It depends on the license with which the original work was published.  Codeproject.com uses their own, "CPOL".  It is pretty vague how selective portions of the "work" are protected.  But probably fair to assume that "You agree not to advertise or in any way imply that this Work is a product of Your own" applies.  If that is correct then it can only be republished with express consent from the author.  A rule that has been violated here many, many times.  The site is a pretty big PITA btw, many questioners ask about bugs and there are always a *lot* of bugs.

Comment: The CPOL states: "The Article(s) accompanying the Work may not be distributed or republished without the Author's consent".

Comment: Without attribution it's plagiarism and without the necessary rights to republish under CC it would also be a copyright infringement (we had a [similar case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316911/1536976) here recently) and without shortening and getting modified to specifically answer this question it (was) probably also a quite bad answer.

Comment: @Trilarion The pictures are very clear and it didn't really need much more explanation, so it wasn't a bad answer. But I flagged it for moderator attention and it already got deleted.

Comment: Personally I would have gone with Bills approach and edited the answer to include a link to the original article, you said yourself it wasn't a bad answer. Too late now though...

Comment: I wouldn't, @Lankymart. Why reward people for plagiarism? Having an answer deleted is a much more eye-opening experience than someone fixing it for you. If the person really wanted to contribute that content in a useful way, they could post a new answer with proper attribution.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree, he could've at least just paraphrased the article and included a link to it. Now there was no original content whatsoever...

Comment: I once helped a user on some Android issue, here on SO. Then he used my answer (with some variations) on CodeProject for writing an article of his. Is this to be considered plagiarism too? By the way, he told me that he did and I agreed  - why not?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi "he told me that he did and I agreed" Then there's no problem? (except for the fact he should've asked beforehand of course)

Comment: No well, I wouldn't like that the case could be interpreted **in reverse**: someone finds a code on Code Project, then comes here and finds my code and thinks it's my answer to be a plagiarism of the one found on CodeProject. I say this because recently I had a **-25** reputation reversal (answer + like). Without even any notification.

Comment: this all sounds like **total bullshit**.  first, it MAY BE that the answer here is "oh, you might need to add an attribution" (based on some incredibly subtle legal opinion - in some particular jurisdiction in which one can read SO).  secondly "Why reward people for plagiarism" this can't be serious?  there's like a "moral social context" on this site that answers are about *showing how clever the answer writer is*?  (you know .. like "doing tests in grade school")  Was this a joke?   What about in a few years when Google will just supply all the answers by synthesizing answers?

Comment: Again I'm not being a smarty-pants - was that just a joke?  "Answer writers must actually be clever - and show effort!"  heh .. what?

Comment: "Why reward people for plagiarism?". Let's start with the assumption that people ask questions because they want answers, and people answer questions because they want to be helpful, not because they get a kick out of earning SO brownie points. This is not a site for publishing original research or for building a career - it is a site for answering questions. Answering an unoriginal question with an unoriginal answer is perfectly acceptable - subject only to copyright concerns.

Comment: @Michael We're not talking about where an answer merely says the same stuff that's already been said somewhere else before on the Internet. You would be entirely right in that case. What we're talking about here is someone who has literally copied and pasted content from another site, without making any changes of their own, and without giving any credit to the person who originally published that information. If nothing else, there *are* copyright concerns there. But even if there weren't, I am shocked and saddened that more people don't have *ethical* concerns with this type of behavior.

Comment: If someone asks me in the street how to find their way to the station, I'm quite happy to show them my map. I don't start by pointing out "I didn't make this map, I mustn't let you see it until I have credited the author". Answering questions on SO is in my view like helping strangers on the street; the only ethical obligation is to help the asker as best you can.

Comment: The user seems to have a history of posting plagiarised answers - I've just flagged a few of them.

Comment: Just share love. What's the biggie? The world still revolves and we learned something. No one died, no animals were harmed. Keep it moving....in summary I think it's a great idea to share knowledge from one site to another site - > i.e. wider audience.....next.....

Comment: @henry so you wouldn't mind if content you put in a lot of effort to write was passed off by someone else as his own?

Comment: @Alexander Derck - "so you wouldn't mind if content you put in a lot of effort to write was passed off by someone else as his own?" That happens every single day and I'm more flattered than anything else - Google Author is my friend and I generally always reap my SEO and credit....If you want to make something private then do not put it on the interwebs. Once uploaded say goodbye to copyrighting IMO. Sure - you can get a DMCA etc etc etc etc but a bullet-proof server knows where to put your DMCA. I'm just sayin' how it is from my experience online....

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In its current state, no that's not acceptable. It's perfectly fine to help people by finding answers to their questions on other sites, but it's not ok to pass that content off as your own. There are two things you can do when you see this kind of thing:

1. Flag for a moderator to delete the post. Make sure you include a link to the original content.
2. Edit the post to include a link to the original source, and indicate in the post body which portions were quoted from the original.

If it looks like the user has a history of plagiarizing from other sources, I'd go with #1. If it looks like an isolated incident, I'd go with #2.

Comment: Sometimes I poke fun at you by asking how you're coping with ex-modship. Sometimes... I wonder how *I'm* coping.

Comment: @BoltClock There are still days when I just want to hang out in the TL, or just *look* at the mod queue for old times' sake. I'll occasionally see a bad tag or something and get annoyed that I can't just clean it up myself, but I'm (mostly) content knowing that flagging works.

Comment: The queue is well and alive at 1.9k. So there is that.

Comment: @BoltClock Ok, I don't need to see that. Thanks! ;)

Comment: Hi @Bill -- help me understand this.  At absolute basic of the world today, is that many sources of text and other information -- **not all, but many** -- are absolutely available to freely copy and use in any way you want, with no limitations, typically with no attribution. ("internet era" children think this is novel, but no different from publishing laws of old - when certain things were "public domain").  **In general** I can't see the slightest problem with copying text from somewhere.  Sure, of course and obviously, in the rare case where it's "copyright" or something, you can't....

Comment: ... (even then it would almost certainly just be fair use in this context, but set that aside) ...  So I'm just unclear what you and also for example Magisch's first decisive comment, means?

Comment: Just to be clear what I'm asking is: do you mean this is not "allowed" on this site in the sense of **"it's not 'fair' if JoeBlow just copies an answer from somewhere .. Joe might get points, etc, for little effort!"**  or, do you mean **"for copyright reasons, in exceptionally rare cases, you can't do that"** ...??

Comment: Note that your comment "but it's not ok to pass that content off as your own" seems to suggest the **former**.

Comment: @joe There is no "rare" case where things are copyrighted. *Everything* is copyrighted *except* in very rare cases. The majority of nations in the world are signatories of the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) agreement, which says that copyright attaches at the moment a work is fixed. So if you create something, you have a copyright on it automatically. You can choose to relinquish that copyright if you want, but without a formal statement otherwise, it is copyrighted and cannot be used without permission.

Comment: Stack Overflow requires that you license your contributions on the site under [cc-by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which delegates a certain number of rights, but does guarantee that attribution is required whenever any of your contributions are used elsewhere. Putting aside the issue of fair use (and clearly a wall of text copy-pasted from somewhere else is *not* fair use), it is completely illegitimate and therefore not allowed on this site for people to plagiarize content from other sources. Points have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Joe: _"many sources of text and other information -- not all, but many -- are absolutely available to freely copy and use in any way you want, with no limitations, typically with no attribution."_ This is not true whatsoever and it's of extreme concern that you believe this.

Comment: heh you glibly say "putting aside fair use...".  OK  :)

Comment: Anyway - you've answered my question I guess.  Fair enough!

Comment: ***"Points have nothing to do with it"*** ok .. so all the comments on this page about answer-writers needing to "not cheat" etc are nutso. Fair enough.

Comment: I'm putting it aside because it is not fair use, under any standard definition, to copy and paste the entire piece of work without giving credit to the person who generated it. There are specific guidelines for fair usage, and none of them are/were met here.